# Using Handler to set Visibile/Invisibile a maker

Tags: android

I'm working with the google map for a project. I'm using an handler to set the marker visible o invisibile. 
If the zoom of the camera is over the a number I have to set the marker invisible or if the zoom is lower than a number I have to set the marker Invisible. I'm using an ArrayList to save all the markers.

I need to create a timer that will continue to work until the application is closed

My problem is that the handler doesn't start.
Below there is my code:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable run = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom > zoomLevel) {

            for (int j = 0; j < players.size(); j++) {
                Marker removeMarker = players.get(j).marker;
                removeMarker.setVisible(false);
            }
        }else {

            for (int j = 0; j < players.size(); j++) {
                Marker removeMarker = players.get(j).marker;
                removeMarker.setVisible(true);
            }
        }

        handler.postDelayed(run, 1000);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this `handler.postDelayed(run, 1000);` needs to be outside of the runnable body

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable run = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom > zoomLevel) {

            for (int j = 0; j < players.size(); j++) {
                Marker removeMarker = players.get(j).marker;
                removeMarker.setVisible(false);
            }
        }else {

            for (int j = 0; j < players.size(); j++) {
                Marker removeMarker = players.get(j).marker;
                removeMarker.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(run, 1000);
```

Comment: try adding the line handler.postDelayed(run, 1000); in the same scope as the one where the handler is defined, but outside of the runnable.

Comment: the handler it's not in a function, I need to create a timer that start when I open the application and every second do the istructions within it

Comment: that's what postDelayed does.

Comment: If you want to start the handler right away, call handler.post(run); instead in your onResume()

Comment: I know, but I can't understand why in this case doesn't do that.

Comment: the runnable won't run on its own, that's why you need the handler in this case to start the runnable. If you add handler.post(run) in your onResume, when your activity begins it will trigger and run the code that's in your runnable.

Comment: I'm glad. For future reference using post means that the handler is starting the runnable right away, whereas the postDelayed runs the runnable after the time delay that you define in millis has elapsed.